# Can flash read child XML from the embed tag?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript

Say I have an flash object embedded in XHTML like so...

```
<object width="600" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
<param name="data" value="somefilename.xml">
<embed src="somefilename.swf" width="600" height="400">
</embed>
</object>
```

I know that there are methods to read, parse, and use the data in "somfilename.xml".  But, in my case the XHTML and the XML are generated dynamically.  I would rather generate both in one step.

So if I embed the XML like this...

```
<object width="600" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
<embed src="somefilename.swf" width="600" height="400">
<data>
<something id="0" whatever="foo bar"/>
<something id="1" whatever="uff da"/>
<something id="2" whatever="1ee7"/>
</data>
</embed>
</object>
```

Can I get to the "/data/something/@whatever" from within my flash app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Flash will not have direct access to the  tag.

Flash does have access to flashvars though. So might be able to encode your xml as a string and put that in flashvars.

Using [flashvars](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html)

But it may be easier just to try loading the XML file as Flash runs. Perhaps check to see when the file gets generated and then load it?

Comment: Too bad, seems that this would be useful.